# Fill Textbox on Button click

Tags: vb.net

How can I make some text appear in RichTextbox1 when I click Button1?

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the Click event of the button and then set the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx) property of the richtextbox:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextbox1.Text = "This is the text"
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! YOUR LIFE SERVER! :D Now i can learn new things thank you very much

Comment: Sir another question, How can i make the text show slow like, My Text is "Help me with this code..... then after 4 seconds a message will appear again "Here is your code....

Comment: @mafia Use a Timer control? What does the book you're learning VB.NET say to do?

Comment: @MafiaHostNub Accept this question as your answer if it was helped you.Then Post a new question and clarify your doubts over there. : )

Comment: WELL SIRS I'M ONLY 13 AND I NEED TO EXPLORE CODES SO I CAN LEARN THEM =/

Comment: @MafiaHostNub: If you are a new programmer, you should never attempt to discover the language or tools by trial and error. You need to find a good book on VB.NET and go through that first. Also please do consider accepting the above answer.

Comment: But i'm only 13 i my parents dont let me buy them D: please i really need the code this will be my first program